# ng-blur and ng-change firing twice

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some elements that have validations like required, minlength, pattern, etc. And this validations are loaded dynamically from the database to the elements through javascript.

I'll try to show you my components as simple as possible. Using only this codes may not result in the same behaviour.

Here on the Template, when I try to change the option of the dropdown, onTaxNoChanged() function fires twice. It's only an example of the problem. I also have some other elements like this that fires events twice on ng-blur.

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $state, PageHelper) {
    //Other codes

    $scope.page_id = $state.params.module + $state.params.submodule;
    $scope.pageHelper = PageHelper;
    $scope.pageHelper.loadPage($scope.page_id);

    //Other codes
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller" id="{{page_id}}" class="page">

    <!-- Other Elements -->

    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="sirketTipi">
            {{'sirketTipi'|translate}}
        </label>

        <select class="form-control"
            id="sirketTipi"
            name="sirketTipi"
            ng-model="fields.partner.sirketTipiLOV"
            ng-change="onTaxNoChanged()"
            ng-options="lov.lovdisplayvalue for lov in pageHelper.components['sirketTipi'].items track by lov.lovvalue.lovid">
            <option value="">{{'PLEASE_SELECT' | translate}}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Other Elements -->

</div>
```

PageHelper factory:

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp');

myApp.factory('PageHelper', function ($timeout, $rootScope) {

    var PageHelper = {};

    //Other Codes

    PageHelper.loadPage = function (pageId, callback, isForcedFetchTXDR) {

        //After some operations

        $timeout(function () {
            preparePageComponents(PageHelper.screens[pageId]);
        });
    }

    var preparePageComponents = function (screen) {

        //After some operations

        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('PREPARE_FORM_VALIDATION');
        });
    }
```

form-group directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('formGroup', function ($rootScope, $compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('PREPARE_FORM_VALIDATION', function () {

                //var contents = element.contents();
                //element.children().remove();
                //element.append(contents);

                // Some changes to the element object

                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem occurs because of the $compile operation at the end of form-group directive's broadcast function(PREPARE_FORM_VALIDATION). It causes the elements compile twice, but if I remove that my validation logic completely stops working.

As you can see on the comments of broadcast function, I've tried the solutions that I've found on the internet while trying to solve the problem. "element.children().remove()" technique prevents my elements' some functions to work properly. I've tried to put broadcast function on the prelink but it's no use.

Is there another way to compile changes to the element on the broadcast function?

Comment: your question is too broad. You should narrow down the amount of code to the lowest one which is able to reproduce the issue and post it on plunker. This is the way of being nice to the people who is going to help you.

Comment: I just wanted people to see that I have some validation operations in the broadcast function. Now I narrowed it down a little more. All of the components are much more complicated, I tried to simplify with important parts as much as possible.